# Неправильное сравнение строк Java

Tags: java, строки, сравнение

Делал программу на Java с помощью Scanner, которая должна при вводе `help` выводить список команд, а если пользователь ввел другое, то выводить "Неизвестная команда". Когда запустилась программа и я ввел `help`, вывелось "Неизвестная команда". Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите команду, используйте help для получения списка команд: ");
        String command = in.nextLine();
        
        if (command == "help") {
            System.out.println("open - открыть файл или папку\n close - закрыть файл или папку\n create - создать файл или папку\n delete - удалить файл или папку");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Неизвестная команда");
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Скажите, где ошибся в написании кода и как это исправить?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Java строки надо сравнивать методом `equals` (как-то так: `command.equals("help")`)...

Comment: Спасибо, теперь программа работает как надо. Насчет же дубликата, мне кажется, что нет, т.к. в том вопросе автор изменил == на equals() и код перестал работать (я так интерпретировал вопрос)

Comment: @Михаил, наоборот, автор дубликата _"...наткнулся на баг, и при замене `==` на `equals` он [баг] пропал.​​​​​​​​​​"_ Это типичная ошибка начинающего, может быть связана с тем, что во многих других ЯП для сравнения строк достаточно оператора `==`.  И класс `Scanner` здесь ни при чём.